# What words do you use to describe an unmatched couple?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

What words do we use to describe an unmatched couple, for instance, the female is much more attractive than the male, or the other way around?

If we found that a girl is out of the league of her boyfriend (8 vs 5), or the other way around, how would we describe such a couple?

Comment: an *unlikely couple*?

Comment: According to Google Books, 7790 writers would call them [*an **ill-matched** couple*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22know+my+seven+times+table%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22an+ill-matched+couple%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: Google turns up about 27,30,000 results for *mismatched couple.*

Comment: @Autoresponder: Which sounds a bit "klunky" to me as a Brit, but apparently [that's the way Americans have gone in recent decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mismatched+couple%2Cill-matched+couple&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmismatched%20couple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cill%20-%20matched%20couple%3B%2Cc0). Both versions carry "negative judgement" connotations though. For a more "neutral" term, I'd go for ***disparate** couple*.

Comment: This question seems to be borne out of a (strange) delusion that a couple is ‘unmatched’ or ‘mismatched’ (or even unlikely) just because one member of it is more traditionally good-looking than the other.

Comment: `a hotty and a notty`?

Comment: Human. All couples are mixed couples in some respects, matched in others. "League" is a reflection of your assumptions, not a reality.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Quite. No doubt many would baulk at the usage, but the question clearly brings to fore that there is obvious disparity- "one is more attractive than the other", which inevitably triggers *ill-matched/mismatched.* *Disparate* is nice, smooth and diplomatic. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: if not the question, certainly some of the answers are. If the question were modified to say that the couple fail to match in some other way (for example one is two foot taller than the other) then some of the answers remain appropriate and others do not. If you choose an undeniable but not unlikely criterion on which they differ (e.g. they're of different sexes), you get different answers again ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers **Disparate** could be useful in constructing a thinly veiled insult against the more attractive member of the couple.

Comment: @Spehro: Feasibly. But equally it could be an admiring description intended to praise the couple for being able to think outside the box by selecting an "unlikely" partner, and/or to be making a success of a relationship that many others might be just too hidebound to even consider for themselves. As ever, context is everything.

Comment: hahaha @FumbleFingers doesn't know his seven times table

Comment: I would call them "intelligent people who aren't shallow like the OP".

Comment: @Fumble - that number seems a little high to me. Check out page 12 of your results.

Comment: @J.R.: Google Books estimated results are often hopelessly inaccurate, and it stops returning any more results after a certain point anyway. My link searched for *"**an** ill-matched couple"* (without the article it claims [27,000 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ill-matched+couple%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)). Also note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ill-matched+couple%2Cmismatched+couple&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cill%20-%20matched%20couple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmismatched%20couple%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: 'Siblings' would be a good word

Comment: @Fumble - Exactly my point. If the estimated results are "often hopelessly inaccurate," then maybe it's ill-advised to claim that "7790 writers would call them an _ill-matched couple_."

Comment: OP's nick is well-chosen.

Comment: @J.R.: On that particular comment, I said ***according to** Google Books*, which is just me ringing the changes on *Google Books **claims***. But what exactly is your point? That you think I overstated the prevalence relative to alternatives? I gave a more trustworthy NGram link comparing *ill-matched* to *mismatched*, and relative prevalence is really the only issue here, not the absolute accuracy of Google's "guesstimates". I really can't be bothered to scroll through that many results every time I post a link showing that some usage does in fact have considerable currency.

Comment: @Fumble - My only point is that some of our newer users might not be aware of those inconsistencies. You & I both know that "7790 writers" means what it means: maybe 500, maybe 50. But four people who have answered this question haven't reached 1,000 rep yet on ELU, so I thought it was worth a mention. I have no problem with _ill-matched couple_ as a worthy suggestion.

Comment: @J.R.: Most of our newer users don't even recognize the difference between citing illiterate or non-native speakers on social networking sites, and *written instances* in Google Books. And I still don't understand how Autoresponder's comment immediately after mine claims *27,30,000 results for **mismatched couple***. I only get [*about 192,000 results*](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?tab=ww&ei=BNqUU8ivKo3nPIXPgZAH&ved=0CBIQ1S4#q=%22mismatched+couple%22) when I search. I've learned something though - ***mismatched*** is predominantly a newer, *American* choice for "couple".

Comment: @Fumble - precisely why it's good for us "veterans" to be careful in the wording of our comments.

Comment: @J.R.: Meh: I'm already a bit hacked off about [being told to be "careful"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer/233746?noredirect=1#comment768480_233746). Today's not a good day for more of the same.

Comment: @Fumble - Sorry I caught you on a bad day then, my friend.

Comment: @J.R.: No worries. I shall now slope off and find some cathartic release in watching a "disturbing" movie. Judging by the reviews, [Enter the Void](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1191111/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) is going to be weird enough to convince me that (relatively speaking) I'm "normal".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Mismatched**
  *[To match unsuitably or inaccurately.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mismatched)*
- She is **[out of my league](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_one%27s_league)**
  the subtitle of the ominous film actually says: "[How can a 10 go for a five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She%27s_Out_of_My_League)?"
- ***She is a 9 and he's a 4*** but the numerical difference is somewhat ameliorated if the man in question is extremely wealthy. Think Anna Nicole Smith, the 26-year-old model who married the 89-year-old [James Howard Marshall II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Howard_Marshall)

Comment: Out of my league is good.  I think someone already mentioned mismatched.  The numbers thing is OK but would have to be used in context.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd  Sorry, but mismatched I did think of *before* your post, I just lost time looking for links.

Answer (score 8):

"She was gorgeous. He must have been funny."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd It exactly answers the question in a round about way. You could do without the first sentence. It's like saying "He has a face for radio". This is a way of describing an unmatched couple.

Comment: I tried to encode assumption in the statement, in as few words as possible. I think it's a tad arrogant to say that two people who are together in a relationship but aren't of the same physical attractiveness level are "mismatched". We don't know what their values are, we don't know why they are together. "She was gorgeous, he must have been funny" is meant to say as much about the speaker as it does about the subjects.

Comment: Someone who thinks this doesn't provide an answer to the question would be mismatched with an intelligent person.

Comment: I once heard a pastor say, "Whenever I see an homely man with a very attractive wife, I say to myself, ‘Now there is a man who knows how to _listen_’."

Answer (score 6):

I think the most polite and descriptive way to say this is *odd couple* as in "they are an *odd couple*, aren't they?".

People know this phrase from the [TV show of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Odd_Couple_%28TV_series%29) which described two roommates who were incompatible in ways that led to amusing conflicts.

Comment: You have an *odd* notion of what's polite.

Answer (score 5):

I would describe such a couple as **incongruous**.

Comment: I would prefer incongruous. (Incongruent sounds to me like it's describing Euclidean geometry.)

Answer (score 5):

The normal term I hear is *mismatch*.  This works for looks, personality, status or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

**Trophy wife** -or- **Boy toy**

Those or terms one might use.

Comment: These really only apply to age differences.

Comment: A boy toy is a toy for a boy. The term for a younger man that is being a "toy"for an (older) woman is a _toy boy_.

Comment: @oerkelens: Perhaps that would make sense, but nonetheless, the phrase for a young man used as a sex object is definitely "boy toy."

Comment: ipso and Kundor are correct, a "boy toy" in this context is a man who is a lesser partner (pretty, younger, dumb...) to a woman. At McDonald's, a "boy toy" gets you a cheap Chinese Transformer toy or whatever. That double meaning would make a lovely SNL sketch.

Comment: It seems _both_ are used... [Toy boy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Toy+Boy) and [Boy toy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boy+toy), so I guess no wrong or right. I still think that _toy boy_ makes more sense.

Comment: *Boy toy* is the term normally used in the US; *toy boy* is the more logical British term.

Comment: @ErikKowal Or perhaps *boy toys* work like *dog toys* and *sex toys*.

Answer (score 1):

I think that possible definition may be an [out-of-sync couple](http://www.mindpub.com/art406.htm).

Often people don't realize that they are not reciprocating enough.

Answer (score 1):

"A very shallow judgment"; perhaps?

Comment: True. But not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JohannesPille It is.

Comment: Care to elaborate? This would answer "What words do you use to describe a statement on how a couple is very unmatched?", but does not qualify as a valid option for said statement itself, imho.

Comment: Its an answer, but it might not be the answer you are looking for. That doesn't make it, not an answer.

Comment: @PhillHealey: It's an answer to some other question.

Comment: 42 Is that the 'answer to the question; ?